# if we change the schema of a table in postgress will the sequence gets auto created?

Tags: postgresql, schema, sequence

Say we have a schema named : "test", a table in it as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.details
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test.details_id_seq'::regclass),
    username character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL
)
```

as we could see id column is a **Sequence** which is already been created in this schema.

now if we create a new schema named "check" and altered details table schema as

```
create schema check
alter table test.details set schema check
```

will the sequence be auto created in check schema?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is an independent database object. If you change the schema of the table, the sequence will remain in the old schema, and the table will continue to use it. You can use `ALTER SEQUENCE` to change the sequence's schema as well, and the default value will continue to work (PostgreSQL stores the parsed default expression rather than the text).

All that becomes easier if you use identity columns to generate keys: there, you don't have to take care of the sequence. It is created automatically and changes schema with the table.

Comment: you might want to add that this is different when using `identity` columns